# Whenever I try to exit Eclipse it asks me to "confirm poor choice"

Tags: eclipse

I just installed Eclipse and whenever I try to exit a prompt will appear asking me to "Confirm Poor Choice" and "you're currently trying to close the problems view".

I don't want to close problem view and I want to keep it but I don't know what to do to change this setting. Do I have to check or click something somewhere in the settings?

[image]

- @nitind when the "confirm poor choice" screen appears and i press alt+ shift + f1 a yellow box appears next to the "confirm poor choice" box. I can't take a screenshot or else another "high contrast" prompt appears. So i took a pic with my camera phone.  [image: yellow box]
- @nitind Whenever i try to press print screen while the yellow box appears on screen i get another box that asks if i want to "turn on high contrast"?  [image: Do you want to turn on high contrast?]

-Here are the two files I downloaded if this info helps. "jdk-8u45-windows-i586 (1).exe" and  "eclipse-windows (1).zip"

Comment: A screenshot would help.

Comment: @nitind couldn't upload a pic through the post because i didn't have 10 Stack Overflow points but i uploaded a pic through an external source.

Comment: Which eclipse version you are using?

Comment: @SumitSingh I'm using Eclipse IDE for Java Developers. Version: Luna Service Release 2(4.4.2).  Build id: 20150219-0600 . I'm using Windows 7 32 bit computer.

Comment: Did you install any other plug-ins? This is not normal. If pressing Alt+Shift+F1 while it's showing and in focus gives you a popup, a picture of the popup would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and fixed it.

In my case it was caused by having the Stanford university plugin.
Go to `Windows->Preferences->Stanford` and turn off the first
checkbox (something about warn about closing the problems view).